# How do I rationalize the following fraction: $\frac{1}{9\sqrt[3]{9}-3\sqrt[3]{3}-27}$?

Tags: fractions, rationalising-denominator

As the title says I need to rationalize the fraction: $\frac{1}{9\sqrt[3]{9}-3\sqrt[3]{3}-27}$. I wrote the denominator as: $\sqrt[3]{9^4}-\sqrt[3]{9^2}-3^3$ but I do not know what to do after. Can you help me?

Comment: It appears [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240818/rationalizing-the-denominator-1-over-n-sqrtkr-pm-sqrt2kr) tackles a general version of this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-yz)=x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz$

With $x=9\sqrt[3]{9},y=-3\sqrt[3]{3},z=-27$ all terms on the right side are rational, try it.  So multiply the given numerator and denominator by $x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-yz$ with $x,y,z$ as rendered above.

Comment: +1 Nice work. I thought there was a quick (but not immediately obvious) way, and you've proved it,

Comment: It works here because the product of the cube root radicands, using $1$ for the radicand in the third term, is a cube.

Answer (score 4):

Let $x=3^\frac13$ then the fraction becomes
$$-\frac{1}{x^4}\cdot\frac{1}{x^5-x^4+1}$$
What we need is to multiply nominator and denominator with some polynomial of $x$ in order to leave only terms with exponents divisible by $3$ in the denominator. How can we find such polynomial?

The answer is simple: find remained when dividing a polynomial by $x^5-x^4+1$ and check if we can obtain such polynomial. Maybe it is confusing, here is an example.

Let's start with $x^6+ax^3+b$. Suppose we want to multiply $x^5-x^4+1$ with something to obtain $x^6+ax^3+1$ (because it will cancel out all cube roots). Here $a,b$ are constants. So, the remainder of the division is
$$x^4+ax^3-x+b-1$$
Then, check if we can chose $a,b$ in such a way to make this remainder $0$. If we can, then we are done. Otherwise check the next polynomial $x^9+ax^6+bx^3+c$. The ramainder is now
$$a x^4+(-a-1) x-a+(b-1) x^3+c-x^2-1$$
Can we chose some $a,b,c$ to make this $0$? No, because $a$ must be $0$ to cancel out $x^4$, but at the same time must be $-1$ to cancel out $x$. So, continue with checking polynomials. x^12+ax^9+bx^6+cx^3+d is the next one we want to check. Here is the remainder
$$x (-a-b+1)+x^3 (-a+c-1)-a x^2-a+(b-3) x^4-b+d+2$$
What we have is basically a system of equations
$$a+b=1\\a-c=-1\\-a=0\\b-3=0\\a-b-d=2$$
This system of equations has no solutions. Let's continue. Remainder for degree $15$
$$x (a-b-c+4)+x^3 (-a-b+d+2)+x^4 (-3 a+c-3)+2 a+(3-b) x^2-b-c+e+4$$
**Good news!** This system has a solution! We have
$$a=-1\\b=3\\c=0\\d=0\\e=1$$
which corresponds to the polynomial
$$x^{15} - x^{12} + 3 x^9 + 1$$
and we want to multiply denominator with
$$1 + x^4 - x^5 + x^8 + x^9 + x^{10}$$

## Solution

As explained above, our polynomial is
$$1 + x^4 - x^5 + x^8 + x^9 + x^{10}$$
But, notice the $\frac1{x^4}$, so we need to multiply our polynomial with $x^2$.

## Verification

Mathematica can verify that this actually works

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Compute the minimal polynomial of $\alpha=-27-3\cdot3^{1/3}+9\cdot3^{2/3}$:
$$
\begin{align}
\alpha&=-27-3\cdot3^{1/3}+9\cdot3^{2/3}\tag1\\
\alpha^2&=567+405\cdot3^{1/3}-477\cdot3^{2/3}\tag2\\
\alpha^3&=-81-25515\cdot3^{1/3}+16767\cdot3^{2/3}\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Since $(-3,405,-25515)\times(9,-477,16767)=-2214(1,81,2430)$, we get that
$$
\alpha^3+81\alpha^2+2430\alpha+19764=0\tag4
$$
Thus, dividing $(4)$ by $19764\alpha$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1\alpha
&=-\frac{\alpha^2+81\alpha+2430}{19764}\\
&=-\frac{45+9\cdot3^{1/3}+14\cdot3^{2/3}}{1098}\tag5
\end{align}
$$