# Rationalizing denominator with any number of radicals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I'm trying to develop a java class for exact algebraic numbers. I've come to a little bit of a roadblock as far as this goes. My question right now is how to rationalize these equations, but no-one I've asked seems to know.

Rationalize $$\frac{1}{a+\sqrt[c_1]{b_1}+\sqrt[c_2]{b_2}+\cdots+\sqrt[c_n]{b_n}}$$

Comment: i think this form is much simpler that its rationalized form if it  exits!!!!!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: chech this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240818/rationalizing-the-denominator-1-over-n-sqrtkr-pm-sqrt2kr/2251027#2251027

Comment: Assuming $c_i\in\mathbb{N}$.  In general, you have
$$
\frac{1}{a+\sqrt[c_1]{b_1}+\sqrt[c_2]{b_2}+\dots+\sqrt[c_n]{b_n}}
=\frac{\prod\limits_{(m_1,\dots,m_n)\neq 0}(a+\zeta_{c_1}^{m_1}\sqrt[c_1]{b_1}+\zeta_{c_2}^{m_2}\sqrt[c_2]{b_2}+\dots+\zeta_{c_n}^{m_n}\sqrt[c_n]{b_n})}{\prod\limits_{(m_1,\dots,m_n)\in C_{c_1}\times\dots\times C_{c_n}}(a+\zeta_{c_1}^{m_1}\sqrt[c_1]{b_1}+\zeta_{c_2}^{m_2}\sqrt[c_2]{b_2}+\dots+\zeta_{c_n}^{m_n}\sqrt[c_n]{b_n})}.
$$the denominator is a polynomial in $a,b_1,\dots,b_n$ with integer coefficients.

Comment: how did you found this formulla????

Comment: Symmetric function theorem.

Comment: Is $n$ even or odd?

Comment: @user10354138 I could not find anything on the "Symmetric function theorem", and also, please explain your zeta notation. I notice you use a zeta with superscript and a subscript. I'm not sure how to evaluate this.

Comment: $\zeta_c=\exp(2\pi i/c)=\cos(2\pi/c)+i\sin(2\pi/c)$ is a primitive $c$-th root of unity.  Raise this to the $m$-th power to get $\zeta_c^m$.

Comment: @user10354138 Sorry to bug you further, however, I failed to mention further things which were unclear to me previously. I'm not sure where to get $M_n$ from, aswell as $C_n$. I'm also a little bit confused on the product notation you used. I'd very much appreciate it if you could further elaborate on these. Sorry for my incompetence, I'm still a student in highschool, so I have a lot left to learn.